# Reledmac endnotes formatted as single paragraph

Tags: endnotes, reledmac

I am using `reledmac` and `reledpar` to typeset translations of ancient texts. I was using critical footnotes but it is better to have the notes after every relevant section so I switched to endnotes.

However, in the following MWE, even though I have `\Xendparagraph[A]`, each note seems to be set on its own line:

[image]

I want them all in sequence (on one or more lines), not in separate paragraphs. Perhaps I have misunderstood the documentation? Or I have introduced a problem in my code....

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
 \documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{reledmac}
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}     % format all A-series critical notes into a single paragraph
    \Xlemmaseparator[A]{:}          % replace ] with : in critical notes
    \Xendlemmaseparator[A]{:}
    \setlength{\linenumsep}{0.5em}  % set space between line number and margin
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}       % subline numbers 'a', 'b', etc.
    \Xendbhooknote{\vskip 6pt\footnoterule}
    \renewcommand{\printnpnum}[1]{}
    \Xendparagraph[A]
\usepackage{reledpar} 
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \firstlinenum*{1}               % start line numbering with first line
    \linenumincrement*{1}           % number every line
    \setstanzaindents{1,0}
    \setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{1em}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}
This is line one&
This is line two\&
\end{astanza}
\begin{astanza}
This is line \edtext{three}{\Aendnote{Alternate}}&
This is line \edtext{four}{\Aendnote{Alternate}}\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering
\autopar
\noindent Translation group one\pend

\noindent Translation group two\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\doendnotesbysection{A}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `\Xendbhooknote{\vskip 6pt\footnoterule}` makes you to get a rule between each notes (`Xendbhooknote` is called before each note, the documentation was unclear, I hope https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/162bb83769591cdb887f5caf4a8bc65d62af1c50 will be clearer).

The version 2.25.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, add `examples/1-verses.aux` `Xendtxtbeforenotes` which insert its mandatory argument before the block of endnotes, if, and only if, there is a least one endnote.

So your MWE becomes

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
 \documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{reledmac}
    \Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}     % format all A-series critical notes into a single paragraph
    \Xlemmaseparator[A]{:}          % replace ] with : in critical notes
    \Xendlemmaseparator[A]{:}
    \setlength{\linenumsep}{0.5em}  % set space between line number and margin
    \sublinenumberstyle{alph}       % subline numbers 'a', 'b', etc.
    \Xendtxtbeforenotes{\vskip 6pt\footnoterule}
    \renewcommand{\printnpnum}[1]{}
    \Xendparagraph[A]
\usepackage{reledpar} 
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.49\textwidth}
    \firstlinenum*{1}               % start line numbering with first line
    \linenumincrement*{1}           % number every line
    \setstanzaindents{1,0}
    \setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{1em}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}

\begin{document}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside} 
\beginnumbering
\begin{astanza}
This is line one&
This is line two\&
\end{astanza}
\begin{astanza}
This is line \edtext{three}{\Aendnote{Alternate}}&
This is line \edtext{four}{\Aendnote{Alternate}}\&
\end{astanza}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering
\autopar
\noindent Translation group one\pend

\noindent Translation group two\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\doendnotesbysection{A}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will be happy to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the clarification offered by Maïeul, a simple workaround in the short term would be to do something like

```
\newcommand{\ruledendnotesbysection}[1]{\vskip 6pt\footnoterule\doendnotesbysection{#1}}
```

and then replace

```
\doendnotesbysection{A}
```

with

```
\ruledendnotesbysection{A}
```

This can of course be generalized to execute whatever code one wishes.

Comment: The problem is in the case you won't have endnotes, you would also get rule.

Comment: Quite right. One should put `\doendnotesbysection{A}` when there are no notes. A bit of a nuisance, I agree.

Comment: See my github messages

Comment: Seen and tested. Looking forward to the release!

Comment: Dont forget to validate the new answer.

Comment: Had not seen it yet. Done!